# How do I replace a string from one column using the data from two other columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My `df` looks something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.98 | 0.01 | SP |
| 1 | 0 | SP |
| 0.89 | SP | 0.1 |
| 0.97 | SP | 0.02 |
| 0.96 | 0 | SP |

I have some idea of how to code this but not quite there,

I want the `df` to become this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.98 | 0.01 | 0.01 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.89 | 0.01 | 0.1 |
| 0.97 | 0.01 | 0.02 |
| 0.96 | 0 | 0.04 |

This is an idea of what I am trying to do but it's not quite right

`df = df.apply(lambda x: float(1 - x['col1'] - x['col2']) if x['col3'] == "SP" else x, axis=1)`

`df = df.apply(lambda x: float(1 - x['col1'] - x['col3']) if x['col2'] == "SP" else x, axis=1)`

Comment: where in your data are the two columns for `x['OVERALL_DESTPER'] - x['UNKNOWNPER']`?

Comment: Changed it, did not realise I hadn't edited to suit the df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try fillna:

```
s = df[['col2','col3']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
SPs = s.isna()

fill= 1 - (s.mask(SPs,0).astype(float).sum(1) + df['col1'])

df[['col2','col3']] = s.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(fill))
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Kyle.

Using [pd.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) gives short, readable code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': [  0.98, 1, 0.89, .97, 0.96],
    'col2': [0.01, 0, 'SP', 'SP', 0],
    'col3': ['SP', 'SP', 0.1, 0.02, 'SP']}
    )

df['col2'].where(df['col2'].apply(type) != str,df['col1'], inplace=True)
df['col3'].where(df['col3'].apply(type) != str, df['col2'], inplace = True)
```

`pd.Series.apply(type)` just calls python's `type` on each value in the series, returning a series of the results

By the way, I wrote out code that created your data from a dictionary using `pd.DataFrame(...)` to create it. In the future, it will be helpful to others if you include this part (or similar) in your example so that they can copy and paste. This is part of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and makes getting high quality answers faster and easier. If you are loading your data with pd.read_csv() you can use DataFrame.to_dict() to get a copy and paste ready output.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1:**
Use `mask` with `replace` and `astype(float)`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float) - df['col3'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].mask(df['col3'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float) - df['col2'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float))
```

If column 1 never has strings, you can simplify with:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'] - df['col3'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].mask(df['col3'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'] - df['col2'].replace('SP', 0).astype(float))

Out[1]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0  0.98  0.01  0.01
1  1.00     0     0
2  0.89  0.01   0.1
3  0.97  0.01  0.02
4  0.96     0  0.04
```

---

**Solution #2:**
Alternatively, use `mask` with `pd.to_numeric()` since you have strings:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'] == 'SP', 1 - pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce') - pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='coerce'))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].mask(df['col3'] == 'SP', 1 - pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce') - pd.to_numeric(df['col2'], errors='coerce'))
df
```

If column 1 never has strings, you can simplify with:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'] - pd.to_numeric(df['col3'], errors='coerce'))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].mask(df['col3'] == 'SP', 1 - df['col1'] - pd.to_numeric(df['col2'], errors='coerce'))
df

Out[2]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0  0.98  0.01  0.01
1  1.00     0     0
2  0.89  0.01   0.1
3  0.97  0.01  0.02
4  0.96     0  0.04
```